# Wkhtmltopdf local storage dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, wkhtmltopdf

I have dependency of local storage while generating the PDF from our application URL.  I am using following code:

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
wkhtmltopdf(
    'http://localhost:8081/ui/main/app/home.html#/analytics/student-report',
    {
        noStopSlowScripts:true,
        javascriptDelay:5000,
        viewportSize: '1280x1024',
        output: 'out3.pdf',
        orientation:'Landscape'
    }, function (code, signal) {
        return callback(null,{code:code,signal:signal})
    }
);
```

Is there any way to simulate local storage.

Comment: you could install a [mock localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-local-storage). But wkhtmltopdf is quite old, I'd look into headless chromium